# What's the purpose for the variable `tmp` in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, function, method-modifier

I'm having troubling understanding the point of the variable `tmp` in the following code:

```
$.extend($.Widget.prototype, {
    yield: null,
    returnValues: { },
    before: function(method, f) {
        var original = this[method];
        this[method] = function() {
            f.apply(this, arguments);
            return original.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    },
    after: function(method, f) {
        var original = this[method];
        this[method] = function() {
            this.returnValues[method] = original.apply(this, arguments);
            return f.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    },
    around: function(method, f) {
        var original = this[method];
        this[method] = function() {
            var tmp = this.yield;
            this.yield = original;
            var ret = f.apply(this, arguments);
            this.yield = tmp;
            return ret;
        }
    }
});
```

Why not simply using a function-local variable `var yield` and completely leaving out `tmp` in `around` method? What purpose does it serve? Is this a common design pattern?

Thanks for some hint.

Comment: temporary. I guess in `f()`, `this.yield` is used which should refer to `original`.

Comment: yes, you could use a var named `yield` ... except `yield` is a (reserved) keyword - the name of a var has no significance

Comment: maybe the this.yield=original is use in the f.apply() function. that's why this.yield data was stored in a temporary variable.

Comment: Why don't you add to your question the way you would write the around function? It will make it easier to point out any differences.

Comment: Regarding the former `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that code comes from [Extending jQuery UI Widgets](http://github.bililite.com/extending-widgets.html), which provides some useful context. That article refers to [Avoiding Bloat in Widgets](http://dealloc.me/2006/12/04/avoiding-bloat-in-widgets/) as the source for the code. However, the original doesn't have the `tmp` variable.

I like the addition of `tmp`, because it avoids a side-effect that the original code has. Consider how the around function is supposed to be used:

```
YourWidgetObject.existingWidgetClass("around", "click", function(){
    console.log("before"); //or any code that you want executed before all clicks
    yield(); // executes existing click function
    console.log("after"); //or any code that you want executed after all clicks
}
```

This will work as expected with or without the `tmp` juggling. The `click` event will now execute your extra code before and after the event.

But if you don't restore `yield` using `tmp`, the object's public method `yield` will now be redefined. So if someone would have the strange idea of just calling `YourWidgetObject.yield()` after using `around`, it would execute whatever existing method `around` has last been applied to (in this case, `click`).

**Added after request for clarification:**

Imagine that you don't restore `yield` at all, nor set it to null. And after the code above, you do this:

```
YourWidgetObject.existingWidgetClass("before", "focus", function(){
    yield(); // executes existing **click** function
}
```

`yield` now executes the click function on focus, which is very unexpected behavior.

Could you just set `yield` to null instead of restoring it with `tmp`? Sure, as it is now, it won't make a difference. But as you might change or add other methods, it's more prudent to make the `around` method unaware of the current state, i.e. it shouldn't have to know that `yield` is always null when it gets called.

As a sidenote, I think this is a terrible `around` method, since putting things around an event is not necessarily what it does - you can call `yield` however many times you want, or not at all. More sensible for a real `around` method would be to accept two callbacks, one to be executed before the event and one after. That way you don't need to expose a `yield` method in the first place.

```
around: function(method, before, after) {
    var original = this[method];
    this[method] = function() {
        before();
        original();
        after();
    }
}
```

Comment: I read your answer again and again and still think that `tmp` unnecessary. The `this.yield` starts with `null` and will always be restored to `null`, how can someone having a strange idea and just call it? Could you give a example to illustrate that scenario please? Thanks.

Comment: Excellent judgement. It really is leaky abstraction for such an `around` wrapper.